# Setting up data and options used by Azure Log Analytics with API Management

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have questions on using Azure Log Analytics for API Management. I cannot find more information on Azure Log Analytics with API Management.

Questions

1. What data is Log Analytics based on by default?
2. Do I need to specify or turn on what data Log Analytics is based on? Screenshot of Log Analytics tool are below
3. What data is in each field in red box under Log and Metric is on the screenshot below?

[image]

Below are two ways to add data to Log Analytics with APIM.

1. API within APIM

   API under APIM instance -> Settings -> Azure Monitor -> enable it ->

   Once it is enabled, it seems all the API instances under the APIM instance will use the settings. That is, data from ALL API instances instead of the one API instance will be added to Log Analytics.

   Is this correct?
2. Under Diagnostics setting

   APIM instance -> Diagnostics settings -> Add diagnostic setting

   This will show up the screenshot above.

   Below is all tables shown under Log Analytics tool

   [image: Log Analytics Tool]

[How to integrate Azure API Management with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights) has no info on Log Analytics.

[Get started with Azure Monitor Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-portal)

Comment: were able to figure this out? I have enabled but telemetry is not appearing in log analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great questions!

AFAIK the answer to your question #1 is, log data (telemetry) is collected by Azure Monitor which is stored in a Log Analytis workspace, which is based on Azure Data Explorer. For more information, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/.

In your case when you try to turn on Log Analytics for APIM then APIM related log data (telemetry) is stored in your Log Analytics workspace repository. To know that APIM related log data and its metrics and dimensions, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftapimanagementservice

AFAIK the answer to your question #2 is yes you need to specify or turn on what all APIM related Log Analytics data needs to be stored in your Log Analytics workspace repository.

IMHO the answer to your question #3 is covered in the answer of question #1.

To understand the APIM log metrics better, I suggest you to go to your APIM resource in Azure portal and go to Metrics tile and create new charts for all the available metrics like capacity, gateway requests, eventhub events. Also you may refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-capacity and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs

Hope this helps!!