# How to push Azure APIM Trace logs into Azure Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm new to Azure and I need to push all the logs from APIM, including the trace logs, into Log Analytics Workspace on the same subscription. What's the best way to do this?

I have enabled Insights and Analytics Workspace with the APIM instance. However, I don't see any trace-related logs(like the request, response, backend request, etc) on the Analytics workspace. Not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up data and options used by Azure Log Analytics with API Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185882/setting-up-data-and-options-used-by-azure-log-analytics-with-api-management)

Comment: Hey. Not exactly. I have an APIM instance running and a Function App linked to it as well.
I get the expected response as well. But I am unable to see the trace logs of the APIM on Analytics Workspace, even after enabling it.

Its probably something to do with my setup. It works when I try to test the setup via Postman but doesnt work when I test it using the inbuilt test feature of the service